# How to initialize a variable that will eventually be set to the response of an async request in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, try-catch, variable-assignment, declaration

Being relatively new to typescript, I've run into a problem that I didn't face in my first project - when declaring a variable *prior* to an api request inside a try-catch seems to throw typescript errors for operations on this variable *after* the try-catch.

I've written sample code to show the issue below.

The `res` is the variable with the issue in question, at the top inside the if statement.

```
  interface AuthApiData {
      message: string;
      success: boolean;
    }

    interface AuthApiRes {
      status: number;
      data: AuthApiData;
    }

    if (router.pathname !== '/login') {
      let res: AuthApiRes;
      
      let status;
      const authenticate = async () => {
        try {
          res = await axiosPrivate.get('/api/gilat');
          status = res?.status;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('authflow err:', err);
        }
      };

      authenticate();

      if (status === 200 && res?.data?.success === true) {
        // I wanted to continue writing code here
      }
    }
```

In case anyone wanted to see where typescript was throwing errors and the error appearing on the tooltip I've put an image at the bottom of the question.

All the code does here is declare a variable `res` before a try-catch statement, then try to use this variable in an if-statement after. Inside the try-catch there is an api request that sets the result to this `res` variable when the asynchronous request is resolved.

If I declare res to be some initial object befitting of the it's interface the error goes away, e.g. `res = { status: 403, data: ... }`.

I also tried initializing its type with:

`let res = AuthApiRes | undefined`

Which fixes the problem but I find it messy or rather I'm unsure if this is just "cheating" typescript.

I don't wish to initialize this variable into this an empty placeholder object, but rather for it to remain unassigned until the api resolves.

Is this possible, and if not how can I remove this error without initializing the variable or setting a union "or" undefined for it's typing during its declaration?

[image: Tooltip error and typescript underline errors]

Comment: As always, post *the actual code*, not images of code

Comment: @CertainPerformance my apologies, my original intent was to show the popup of the errors as well as the underlines of where the errors were cuz of typescript else i thought it may be difficult to pinpoint where typescript was highlighting as errors. I guess i could have written it out. Will edit into actual code in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried initializing its type with:
>
> `let res: AuthApiRes | undefined`
>
> Which fixes the problem but I find it messy or rather I'm unsure if > this is just "cheating" typescript.

When a variable is declared but not initialized, its value is `undefined`, for this typescript does not complain when you add `undefined` with the union.

For me the best way is to initialize `res` to `null`, and then check it:

```js
let res: AuthApiRes | null = null;

if(res) {
  if(status === 200 && res.data?.success === true) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The same with the `status` variable.

If you do not like this approach, you could prefix `res` with `!`

`let res!: AuthApiRes`

This hints typescript that you will actually assign a value to `res`, but you will lose typescript checks, and for me, it is not worth.

Comment: Thanks, I can accept this I guess. I was mainly afraid there was something wrong with my using a union here but it seems like it's not abnormal to do so in this situation. And also appreciate the tip on the !, I didn't know that existed but I concur - it's probably not worth it.